# IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running this short code and seeing this error repeatedly no matter what i'm doing when the file reaches df.reset_index.

```
hold = pd.read_excel('/filepath/GTRFigure16.xlsx', sheetname = 'Data')
df = hold.copy()

df.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

I'm under the impression the problem is when i import the excel file i'm using, it's creating a multi-index that includes a totally NaN column. If that's the case, i'm not sure what i can do to solve it, and if it isn't, i'm out of ideas.

Here's the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/us_grains/us_gulf_vessel_loading_activity/us_gulf_vessel_loading_activity.py", line 102, in <module>
    df.reset_index(inplace = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3024, in reset_index
    level_values = _maybe_casted_values(lev, lab)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2989, in _maybe_casted_values
    values = values.take(labels)
IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.
```

Here is a sample of the dataframe this is happening with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({u' ': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): np.nan,
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'In Port',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 u'Due': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'prior 4-yr avg',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'10-days',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 u'Gulf': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): np.nan,
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): 36,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'In Port',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): 39},
 u'In port': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'average',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'4-year',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 u'Loaded': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'4-year avg',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'prior',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 u'PNW': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): np.nan,
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'In Port',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 'Unnamed: 10': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'7-Days',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'Loaded',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 'Unnamed: 11': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'10-days',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'Due',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 'Unnamed: 12': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'Week #',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): 2,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): np.nan,
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): 1},
 'Unnamed: 14': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): np.nan,
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'Loaded',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 'Unnamed: 2': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'7-Days',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): 64,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'Loaded',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): 58},
 'Unnamed: 4': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'10-days',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): 72,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'Due',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): 62},
 'Unnamed: 7': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'7-Days',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'Loaded',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 'Unnamed: 8': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): u'10-days',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'Due',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan},
 u'Vancouver': {(np.nan, u'Date', np.nan): np.nan,
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 11, 0, 0), u'01/11/1995'): np.nan,
  (np.nan, np.nan, np.nan): u'In Port',
  (np.nan, datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 4, 0, 0), u'01/04/1995'): np.nan}})
```